# How to know if a JCalendar is empty?

Tags: java, swing, select, jcalendar

I have a simple Java program with a **JCalendar**.
I need to know if my JCalendar `calendario` is or not empty, it means if the user selected or not a date. I was thinking about a method like `calendario.isEmpty` but it doesn't exist. Maybe I can compare `calendario` with `null` but it didn't work.
I am using `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser`, the best way is check the returned date invoking the instance method `getDate()`. If the returned date is `null`, that means that the user has not selected a date. e.g.:

```
public class TestCalendar extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  private JDateChooser dateChooser;

  public TestCalendar() {
    super("Simple");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
    add(dateChooser);
    JButton button = new JButton("Check");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button);
    setSize(300, 100);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Date date = dateChooser.getDate();
    if (date == null) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestCalendar.this, "Date is required.");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestCalendar().setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as well

```
if(jDateChooser1.getDate()==null){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Date not selected");
}
```